# having the brand and hamburger aalign to left and right and not to the center in xs view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following menu:

```
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2 collapse" style="">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link">menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <div class="mx-auto order-0 mobiler">
                    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">brand</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2 collapse" style="">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Using bootstrap 4 I create a left menu, a right menu and the brand (and in mobile the hamburger) are in the middle. Alas when in mobile xs view the are both centered and I would like them to appear on the left and right side.

I tried playing with media queries and i keep messing up my format.
please help

Comment: Why is Bootstrap 3 included in the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

try using bootstrap 4:

```css
.navbar-brand{
 position: absolute;
}

 /*media queries for mobile view*/
@media (max-width: 575px){
 .navbar-brand{
 right: 10px; 
 top: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav  mr-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">menu item</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="right-menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">menu item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```